# Static resources in Spring not working. Any ideas?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, static-resource

### Situation:

I have a fresh spring project from start.spring.io
And I have created the file `project/src/main/resources/js/a.js`

I have created also `project/src/main/resources/templates/index.html` (it's with thymeleaf)
that needs that `a.js` by `<script th:src="@{/js/a.js}"></script>`

I also have the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/js/");

    }
}
```

When the app is starting I can see in the logs:
`Mapped URL path [/js/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]`

### Tried:

1. At the  `.addResourceLocations();` I have tried all kind of variants like:
   `"/resources/js"`, `"resources/js"`, `"/js"`, `"js"`
2. Also in `application.properties` used `spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/resources/`
3. create `/resources/static/js/a.js` and update the `addResourceLocatios` parameter accordingly

Any ideas?

Comment: can you able to show your folder structure

Comment: put it in `webcontent` or `webapp` folder . If still it doesnt work have you configured any interceptor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to place `a.js` file inside static folder. I have attached folder structure below:

[image]

Also remove your `MvcConfig` since it is not required.

Comment: It works with no configuration whatsoever. Just put everything in `static` folder and your ready. No config in application.properties or in other places needed.